# Respond HTTP 200 and continue processing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a scenario where I need to first respond with HTTP 200 to a server request (due to a time limit) and then continue processing with the actual work.

I also can not use threads, processes, tasks, queues or any other method that would allow me to do this by starting a parallel "process".

My approach is to use the build in "Simple HTTP" server and I am looking for a way to force the server to respond with HTTP 200 and then be able to continue processing.

The current code will receive a POST request and print its content after a 3 seconds. I put a placeholder where I would like to send the response.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time

class MyWebServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):    
    def do_POST(self):        
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)        
        self.send_response_only(200)
        self.end_headers()
        # force server to send request ???
        time.sleep(3)
        print(post_data)        

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=MyWebServer, port=8000):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print('Starting httpd...')
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

Comment: `I also can not use threads, processes, tasks, queues or any other method that would allow me to do this by starting a parallel "process".` Curious, why?

Comment: My code is running on [Zeit Now](https://zeit.co/home) - a serverless cloud service that does not support it.

Comment: Maybe `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` can help here. It allows you to send a status 200 and some other Header info and then send chunks of data.. Needs HTTP >= 1.1 . [Have a look at this dicsussion](https://dev.to/anoff/how-to-create-a-streaming-http-interface-in-python--ceh/comments)

Comment: Thanks for the info. I doubt the client (another server) is supporting chunked transfer though. I am really looking to completely close the current HTTP request and then proceed with my program.

Comment: Maybe you can inherit the HTTPServer class and add the work after the method that handles the incoming requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround solution. You can force the server to send a 200 OK and continue processing after with these two commands:

```
self.finish()
self.connection.close()
```

This solution is from this SO question: [SimpleHTTPRequestHandler close connection before returning from do_POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594418/simplehttprequesthandler-close-connection-before-returning-from-do-post-method)

However, this will apparently close the internal IO buffer that the server uses and it won't be able to server any additional requests after that.

To avoid running into an exception it works to terminate the program (which works for me). However this is just a workaround and I would still be looking for a solution that allows the server to keep processing new requests.

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):    
    def do_POST(self):        
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)        
        self.send_response_only(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.finish()
        self.connection.close()                    
        time.sleep(3)
        print(post_data)
        quit()

def run(server_class=HTTPServer, handler_class=MyHandler, port=8000):
    server_address = ('', port)
    httpd = server_class(server_address, handler_class)
    print('Starting httpd...')
    httpd.serve_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":   
    run()
```